# How to add validation to the 'Add Case Role' option in Case Summary View?

Tags: extension, civicase, developer

I have a customer where it is vital that there is only one Case Role on a case. In the CaseView form it is possible to add a case role, and I want to add some validation to this.
in core actual processing is done in a jQuery function, with the callback function at CRM_Contact_Page_AJAX::relation.

I can do nothing with a validateForm hook here, so what I am planning to do is:

1. create a 'dummy' page with my own version of CRM_Contact_Page_AJAX::relation with the desired validation included
2. replace the template for CaseView with a local version, linking to the new function with the alterTemplate hook

Unfortunately this solution is not viable for a true generic extension. Any better ideas? If not, I will add the instruction to the README and still publish the extension as it might be useful for others too but I wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: Whilst doing this I ofcourse found that I can not use the alterTemplateFile hook as CaseView is a Page rather than a Form....

Comment: Is it that you want one and only one case role per case, or one of *each* role. I'm not quite sure how it can be the former because technically "Case creator" and "Case client" are both roles, so a freshly created case will already have 2.

Answer (score 1):

Futher investigation has given me at least one answer. I can create my own template file with new jQuery functions using my new function as a callback. In that new jQuery function I can replace the .onClick functions for the button 'add Role' and the edit pencil. But still open to better suggestions!